# Assembly Language Integer registers

Tags: assembly, i386

I don't understand what this assembly instruction does. What is its effect and why?

```
imull $16, (%eax, %edx,4)
```

The initial values of the registers are

```
%eax= 0x100x
%edx= 0x3
```

Comment: How would I solve? I don't see a problem in the first place. Are you asking what would the result be?

Answer (score 9):

I'm assuming you're trying to understand how to interpret that AT&T style assembly instruction, in particular the addressing part. I'm sure you don't need help understanding what the `imull $16` part does - it simply performs a signed multiplication, the last `l` standing for `long` word.

`(%eax, %edx, 4)` is a form of addressing, where you have a base address, an offset of a certain amount of elements, and a scale/multiplier for multiplying the number of elements by the size of each one: `(base, offset, offset scale/multiplier)`.

What you end up with is `(base + (offset * multiplier)`, so in this case it'll be:

```
(%eax + (%edx * 4))
(0x100 + (0x3 * 4))
(0x100 + 0xC)
(0x10C)
```

Therefore the instruction `imull $16, (%eax, %edx,4)` performs a signed multiplication of `16` by the value of the long word at the address `0x10C`.

Answer (score 1):

The result of this instruction will be whatever `dword` is stored at the address `0x10c` multiplied by 16 (or, if you prefer, shifted to the left by 4 bits). The result will be written to that address as well.

Comment: how did you find the address to be 0x10c

Comment: this wat i did 0x3 + 4= 0x7 then 0x7 + 0x100=? this where i am confused