# Where are the outputs of assembly instructions stored?

Tags: c, assembly

If I have an instruction:

```
imull $eax, $ecx
```

so that it is multiplying what is stored in the two registers, where is the answer stored?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458537/assembly-language-integer-registers

Comment: Read the question. I know what the operation is performing. Where is it being stored. Back into $eax possibly?

Comment: Batter explanation here http://www.csi.ucd.ie/staff/jcarthy/home/alp/alp2-3.html

Comment: The inputs and outputs are documented along with each instruction in Intel's Developer's Manual. Since you're using AT&T syntax rather than Intel, the ordering of the operands is different, which affects instructions with explicit destinations, like the one in your question. Adrian's answer is correct, but I wouldn't call it the property of the assembler, more a property of the assembler dialect being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different assemblers work differently.   For the GNU Assembler the result will go in `$ecx`.  This is the opposite convention from most windows assemblers.